# Conditional Automated Email Alerts in SP2007 based on list entries

Tags: 2007, workflow, email, expiration

I need a SP 2007 list to auto generate and send an email to an email address that is an attribute in the list 60 days prior to an expiration date that is also an attribute in the list, without 3rd party utilities (I cannot install anything on this box and have to work with what's there - SP 2007).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple overview of how this code might look in designer:

```
Set Variable: emailAddress to Current Item:Client Email
then Add 60 days to Today (Output to Variable: pauseUntilDate)
then Pause until Variable: pauseUntilDate
then Email Variable: emailAddress
```

So what's happening here? For simplicity sake I am using variables to manage the date we are pausing to, and the email address we are sending to.

The key actions here are the `Add Time to Date` and the `Pause Until Date`. The former allows us to add 60 days to today's date, while the latter allows us to pause execution of the rest of the workflow until the paused date.

The email address is found by doing a lookup on a field in the current item.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback.  However I don't beleive I have access to designer software that seems to be commonly referenced here.  I can create and manage sites and lists in sharepoint 2007 but that is the extent of my tools or access.  Is there any way to do this without Designer?  Is Designer a standard part of SP 2007, such that we should have it if we have SP 2007 and maybe I just don't have access to it?  I apologize if these are stupid questions..  Thank you for your help and response above.

Comment: @Griever yes, SharePoint Designer is--among other things--the tool you use to manage your workflows. I recommend you contact your sysadmin or IT about getting it installed. It is absolutely necessary to doing tasks like this.